# why this.state.text is throwing an error in function?

Tags: reactjs

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

  onformsubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.text);
  }

  state = { text: '' }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui segment">
        <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.onformsubmit}>
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search: </label>
            <input type='text'
              onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ text: e.target.value }) }} //rerendered
              value={this.state.text} // overwrite by state.text 
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

so I was trying to stop the loading of the new page whenever user press 'ENTER' so I wrote a function called onformsubmit() to prevent the default behaviour then I tried to print the state value it's showing an error "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". I searched it I was not able to get the exact reason.

Comment: Because your `onformsubmit` changes the context and `this` belongs to the function at that point rather than the class. One of myriad reasons to use Hooks.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

`this` from the class component isn't bound to the `onformsubmit` handler function, so `this.state` is undefined.

## Solution

Either bind `this` to `onformsubmit` in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props0;
  this.onformsubmit = this.onformsubmit.bind(this);
  ...
}
```

Or convert `onformsubmit` to an arrow function so `this` is bound automatically for you.

```
onformsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.text);
}
```